# How to keep the choices of previous questions alive in a test?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am making an Online Test using CSS/JS/JSP+servlets+MySQL. But every time i go to the previous question, the selected radio button disappears and it appears as if i am attempting it for the first time. What i want is that the value of option gets saved so that when i move to any of the attempted question, it shows which option i had selected. I dont want to use Swing/awt. Also it is a part of a bigger project so consider that.I hope that this can be done on client side itself. I am fetching questions from an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) in order to store data as small as question answers. Of course this means the data is stored client side and would need to be accessed from there then communicated to a server.